# Does the res(500) is doing the end

Tags: node.js, express

I use the following code in express response does

```
res.status(500).send("Error : " + err);
```

Do I need to add **end** or when I send the 500 it automatically to the end?
If I use it like this it can cause a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include .end when using .send, but you do if you only use .status - see the documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) for all of the cases which will automatically end the response for you.

```
res.status(404).end(); // OK

res.status(404).send('Error'); // OK
```

Comment: just to verify,So if I use it with 500 its OK?I dont need to use end...?